# PyTorch Binary classification not learning

Tags: python, pytorch

I state that I am new on PyTorch. I wrote this simple program for binary classification. I also created the CSV with two columns of random values, with the "ok" column whose value is 1 only if the other two values are included between two values I decided at the same time. Example:

```
diam_int,diam_est,ok
37.782,125.507,0
41.278,115.15,1
42.248,115.489,1
29.582,113.141,0
37.428,107.247,0
32.947,123.233,0
37.146,121.537,0
38.537,110.032,0
26.553,113.752,0
27.369,121.144,0
41.632,108.178,0
27.655,111.279,0
29.779,109.268,0
43.695,115.649,1
44.587,116.126,0
```

It seems to me all done correctly, loss actually lowers (it comes back up slightly after many epochs but I don't think it's a problem), but when I try to test my Net after the training, with a sample batch of the trainset, what I got is always a prediction below 0.5 (so always 0 as estimated output) with a completely random trend.

```
with torch.no_grad():
        pred = net(trainSet[10])
        trueVal = ySet[10]
        for i in range(len(trueVal)):
            print(trueVal[i], pred[i])
```

Here is my Net class:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F

class Net(nn.Module):
    
    def __init__(self) :
        super().__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(2, 32)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(32, 64)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(64, 1)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = F.relu(self.fc2(x))
        x = self.fc3(x)
        return torch.sigmoid(x)
```

Here is my Main class:

```
import torch
import torch.optim as optim
import torch.nn.functional as F
import pandas as pd

from net import Net 

df = pd.read_csv("test.csv")
y = torch.Tensor(df["ok"])
ySet = torch.split(y, 32)
df.drop(["ok"], axis=1, inplace=True)
data = F.normalize(torch.Tensor(df.values), dim=1)
trainSet = torch.split(data, 32)

net = Net()
optimizer = optim.Adam(net.parameters(), lr=0.001)
lossFunction = torch.nn.BCELoss()
EPOCHS = 300

for epoch in range(EPOCHS):
    for i, X in enumerate(trainSet):
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        output = net(X)
        target = ySet[i].reshape(-1, 1)
        loss = lossFunction(output, target)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

    if epoch % 20 == 0:
        print(loss)
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance for the help

Answer (score 2):

Your model is *underfit*. Increasing the number of epochs to (say) `3000` makes the model predict perfectly on the examples you showed.

However after this many epochs the model may be *overfit*. A good practice is to use validation data (separate the generated data into train and validation sets), and check the validation loss in each epoch. When the validation loss starts increasing you start overfitting and stop the training.

Comment: I think it's not the problem. After about 200 epochs loss starts to increase and it overfits. I tried to just modify EPOCHS to 1000 but the result is the same: all outputs below 0.5 and they don't seem to follow a particularly different trend when the real target is 0 or 1.

Comment: @Giorgio I ran your code on the example data and it managed to overfit. You did not provide the whole data, so that might be the difference. Although, overfitting on the train data does not mean that the loss increases. Loss should decrease on the train data as you overfit. Your problem might be caused by some inconsistency in the data, or an imbalance (if there are much more data for target 0).

Comment: Sorry for my late feedback. As you said this is not the whole data. The full data contains 10k samples and they are consistent but they are unbalanced: there are many more 0 than 1. I thought this could be the problem but I would like my neural network to work in these exact conditions. So, how can I fix this? Do I need to change the loss function? Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Giorgio The loss function is not an issue in my opinion. I think you should try increasing the number of neurons in the layers to increase model complexity. It seems like it is not complex enough to capture your pattern, and that's why it underfits.

Comment: I increased the complexity with more attempts, even reaching 5 layers with 128 neurons for each hidden layer. The result is exactly the same: the loss decreases only for the first epochs then increases and decreases around the same value and outputs are always below 0.5 (which at this point I believe is due to the majority of 0, conditions in which, however, I would like it to work anyway)

Comment: Note (if that helps): I noticed that when the real target is 1 the output value of the neural network is a high number (but always less than 0.5). The problem is that this number is still high sometimes when the target is 0 and comparable with the values ​​of when it is 1. In particular I noticed a repetition of the output 0.4018 (maximum value obtained as output in the current neuron conditions in which I am testing the network), in both some cases of real target 0 or 1, in a way it seems random. Can this strange repetition of the exact same number mean anything?

Comment: Fewer layers with more neurons could be better (e.g 2 layers with 1024 or something like that). If the problem persists, you could try to decrease the "confidence level" from 0.5 to say 0.25, and treat predictions over 0.25 as positive.